# what is wrong with this code and why is it not printing anything

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    int i=0;

    string s1 = "";

    s1[i++]='F';
    s1[i++]='U';
    s1[i++]='A';
    s1[i++]='A';
    s1[i++]='D';
    
    cout << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s1` is *empty*, any indexing into it will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*. Do e.g. `s1 += 'F'` instead.

Comment: And please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Doing `using namespace std;` is also [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) but usually considered okay for small examples.

Comment: Similar code will actually work in C, if you replace `string` by `char s1[99] = ""`. Maybe you took your code from someone who programmed C and not C++? Or from a very old book?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to modify elements in an empty string.

If you want your code to work there are several ways to do this:

- add elements to `s1`, you can use `s1 += 'A'` or `s1.push_back('A')` instead.
- Allocate enough space to modify each element by doing `s1.resize(5)` after `string s1 = "";`.

And possibly more, but that should get you started. Think of `std::string` as an array of characters. If your array is empty, you either have to resize it or add things to it.

Note: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` just do `#include <string>`.

Note: Avoid using `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

`s1` is *empty*, any indexing into it will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*. Do e.g. `s1 += 'F'` instead. – Some programmer dude

Comment: Remember that S1 is a "string" C++ object here, not a plain array.